# Add value text for value_counts().plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Given a code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','A','B','B','C'], columns = ['letters'])
df.value_counts()
df.letters.value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Out:

[image]

I would like to add value text for each bar, how could I do that in Matplotlib? Thanks.

**Updated code and dataset:**

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
  letters  numbers
0       A       10
1       A        4
2       A        3
3       B       12
4       B        7
5       C        9
6       C        8
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = [0, 5, 10, 20]
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['numbers'], bins = bins)

def addlabels(x, y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.text(i, y[i], y[i])

plt_df = df.binned.value_counts().sort_values()
plt.bar(plt_df.index, plt_df.values)
addlabels(plt_df.index, plt_df.values)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `Value = 2` on top of each bar?

Comment: Yes, exactly adding values on the top of each bar.

Comment: You have to determine the counts and add them as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372659/8881141).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def addlabels(x,y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.text(i, y[i], y[i], ha = 'center')

df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','A','B','B','C'], columns = ['letters'])
plt_df = df.letters.value_counts().sort_values()

plt.bar(plt_df.index, plt_df.values)
addlabels(plt_df.index, plt_df.values)
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, I will, but testing with my real data, it raisea an error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'`, `df.letters` is replaced by `df['binned']` obtained from `df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['counts'], bins = bins)`.

Comment: Could u help to deal this issue?

Comment: What are the bins? Share your dataset.

Comment: I updated data and code, please check.

Comment: The problem solved by using `pd.cut(df['numbers'], bins = bins).astype(str)`, many thanks.

Comment: Yes, i  was about to post it. My pleasure.